# How to solve $x^2+11=y^3$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, mordell-curves

I've been trying to solve the diophantine $$x^2+11=y^3$$ recently but to no avail. I tried the "UFD trick", re-writing as $(x-i\sqrt{11})(x+i\sqrt{11})=y^3$, but it didn't give me all the solutions. I found $(x,y)=(\pm 58, 15)$ but missed $(\pm 4, 3)$, and now I'm unsure if these are all the solutions.

Does anyone know of a solution to this problem?

Comment: ? The solution you "missed" appears to be the solution you found?  This must be a typo.

Comment: the other is (4,3)

Comment: The UFD method *does* work, but you need to be in the UFD $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{-11})/2] = \{(a+b\sqrt{-11})/2 : a \equiv b \bmod 2\}$, not in the non-UFD $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-11}]$. The usual method shows $x+\sqrt{-11}$ is a cube in $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{-11})/2]$, so you can write it as $((a+b\sqrt{-11})/2)^3$, where $a \equiv b \bmod 2$. Comparing coefficients of $\sqrt{-11}$, $1 = (3a^2-11b^2)b/8$. If $a$ and $b$ are even then $a = \pm 4$ and $b = 2$, leading to $x = \pm 58$ and $y = 15$. If $a$ and $b$ are odd then $a = \pm 1$ and $b = -1$, leading to $x = \pm 4$ and $y = 3$.

Comment: Nice.  But how can one see that $\Bbb{Z}[1+\sqrt{-11}/2$ is a UFD? Is a similar statement true any time we have $x+\sqrt{-(4m+3)}$ which is the ugly case for the usual trick?

Comment: @MarkFischler, what are some rings that you know how to show are UFDs already, and by what methods? (Not by a long shot can you replace 11 with any positive $4m+3$ and expect to have a UFD.)